# How to show that $S=|a_i|/(|b_i|\cos \theta)$ is incompatible with $S=S_{ij}l_il_j$ given $S_{ij}=S_{ji}$ and $a_i=S_{ij}b_j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

The scalar magnitude $S$ of a symmetric 2nd-rank tensor $S_{ij}$ in the direction given by the unit vector $l_i$ is defined as:
$$\tag{1} S=S_{ij} l_i l_j$$

The relationship between vectors $a_i$ and $b_i$ is defined as:
$$\tag{2} a_i=S_{ij}b_j$$

**How can it be shown that the relation**,
$$\tag{3} S=\frac{|a_i|}{(|b_i|\cos \theta)},$$

where $\cos \theta$ is the angle between the vectors $a_i$ and $b_i$, **is incompatible with Eqn(1) given Eqn(2)?**

Note, it can be shown that the relation $S=|a_i|\cos \theta /|b_i|$ is compatible with Eqn(1) given Eqn(2) via the following:
$$\tag{4} S=S_{ij}l_il_j=\frac{S_{ij}b_jb_i}{|b_i|^2}=\frac{a_i\cdot b_i}{|b_i|^2}=\frac{|a_i||b_i|\cos \theta}{|b_i|^2}=\frac{|a_i|\cos \theta}{|b_i|}$$

What I've tried is the following, but I am not sure if this works:
$$\tag{5} S=\frac{|a_i|}{|b_i|\cos \theta}=\frac{|a_i|^2}{|a_i|b_i|\cos \theta}=\frac{|a_i|^2}{a_i \cdot b_i}=\frac{|a_i|^2}{S_{ij}b_j \cdot b_i}=\frac{|S_{ij}b_j||S_{ij}b_j|}{S_{ij}b_ib_j}\neq S_{ij}l_il_j$$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ContraKinta Please see highlighted question in bold and added equation 5.